# syntax error at prog.pl line 24, But I do not know why

Tags: perl, hash

I am a beginner here and I thought everything was going great until I received this error message: **syntax error at prog.pl line 24, near "SignificanceofPlate"
Execution of prog.pl aborted due to compilation errors.** Can someone please help and explain what is wrong with line 24? If there is something wrong with line 24, shouldn't there be something wrong with all the lines containing "SignificanceofPlate"? They're all the same.
Line 24 is the first "SignificanceofPlate" under Alaska. I was thinking it was too long so I shortened the name, but I still ran across the same problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Perl Assignment - Hash of Hashes
# J Student

# Teams using a Hash of Hashes



# Alaska      1967     The Last Frontier
# Massachusetts  1928     No Motto
# New York   1966      New York
#Vermont     1960      See Vermont
# Mississippi     2019     No Motto #Driver's county of residence replaces motto. I do not approve of this.

# I have created the following array:

@teams = ("Alaska", "New Mexico", "New York", "Vermont" , "Hawaii");

# and the following Hash of Hashes:

%myTeams = ( "Alaska" => { bestYear => 1967,
                                   Motto => "The Last Frontier",
                                   Color=> "Yellow on Blue"
                                   SignificanceofPlate=> "Totem pole on plate"
                                   priceOfplate=> "$300+"
                                  },
              "Massachusetts" => { bestYear => 1928,
                                    Motto => "Massachusetts did not have mottos on their plates until 1990's"
                                   Color=> "White on Green"
                                   SignificanceofPlate=>"Bad omen plate; 1st time any state put a picture of anything on a plate and it was a fish. But this fish is swimming away from the word Mass. 1928, fisherman did not catch any fishes. Fisherman blamed the DMV"
                                   priceOfplate=>"200+"
                                    
                                  },
              "New York" => { bestYear => 1966,
                                    Motto => "New York",
                                    Color=> "Yellow on Blue"
                                    SignificanceofPlate=>"Nothing, I just simply love the color combination"
                                    priceOfplate=>"30.00+"
                                    
                                  },
                    "Vermont" => { bestYear => 1961,
                                    Motto => "See Vermont",
                                    Color=>"White on Green"
                                    SignificanceofPlate=> "Nothing, But it's a switch up from regular color license plates"
                                    priceOfplate=> "20.00+"
                                    
                                  },
                       "Mississippi" => { bestYear => 2019,
                                    Motto => "No motto", #Though someone will say, it's the 'In God We Trust' Plate
                                    Color=> Blue on Gold
                                    SignificanceofPlate=> "This is a very controversial plate because it feature the words, 'In God We Trust' on the plate" #It's mind boggling to me why it's controversial because Mississippi is a highly religious state. Possibly the most religious state.
                                    priceOfplate=> "8.99" #This is very tricky because these plates are new so not many people are selling them. But I imagine they'll be expensive throughout the years. I have mine already :)
                                  },

);

# To print out sorted Team information in the Hash of Hashes (ascending order):

print ("\n\nMy Team - sorted by Team Name ascending:\n\n");

printf("%-20s \t%-6s \t%-10s \t%-25s \n", "Team", "Year", "Owner", "Leader");

@sortedKeys = sort (@teams);

for $teamName (@sortedKeys) {
    $bestYear = $myTeams{$teamName}{'bestYear'};
    $Motto = $myTeams{$teamName}{'Motto'};
    $Color = $myTeams{$teamName}{'Color'};
    $SignificanceofPlate = $myTeams{$teamName}{'SignificanceofPlate'};
    $priceOfplate = $myTeams{$teamName}{'priceOfplate'};

    printf("%-20s \t%-6i \t%-10s \t%-25s \n", $teamName, $bestYear, $Motto, $Color, $SignificanceofPlate, $priceOfplate);
    print "\n";
}

# To print out sorted Team information in the Hash of Hashes (descending order):

print ("\n\My Team - sorted by Team Name decending:\n\n");

printf("%-20s \t%-6s \t%-10s \t%-25s \n", "Team", "Year", "Motto", "Color", "Significance", "Price");

@reverseKeys = reverse (@sortedKeys);

for $teamName (@reverseKeys) {
    $bestYear = $myTeams{$teamName}{'bestYear'};
    $Motto = $myTeams{$teamName}{'Motto'};
    $Color = $myTeams{$teamName}{'Color'};
    $Significanceofplate = $myTeams{$teamName}{'SignificanceofPlate'};
    $priceOfplate = $myTeams{$teamName}{'priceOfplate'};
    
    printf("%-20s \t%-6i \t%-10s \t%-25s \n", $teamName, $bestYear, $Motto, $Color, $SignificanceofPlate,  $priceOfplate );
    print "\n";
}

print "\n\nHTML Page containing information on my Team:\n\n";

print "<html>\n";
print "<head>\n";
print "<title>My Team</title>";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "<H1>License Plates</H1>\n";
print "<table border=1>\n";
print "<tr><th>Team</th><th>Year</th><th>Motto</th><th>Color<tr><th>Significance</th><th>Price</th></tr>\n";
for $teamName (sort keys %myTeams ) {
    $bestYear = $myTeams{$teamName}{'bestYear'};
    $Motto = $myTeams{$teamName}{'Motto'};
    $Color = $myTeams{$teamName}{'Color'};
    $SignificanceofPlate = $myTeams{$teamName}{'SignificanceofPlate'};
    $priceOfplate = $myTeams{$teamName}{'priceOfplate'};

   print "<tr><th>Team</th><th>Year</th><th>Motto</th><th>Color<tr><th>Significance</th><th>Price</th></tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";
```

Marker `<` indicates missing `,` (other blocks are missing `,` as well)

```
"Alaska" => { bestYear => 1967,
              Motto => "The Last Frontier",
              Color=> "Yellow on Blue"                    <
              SignificanceofPlate=> "Totem pole on plate" <
              priceOfplate=> "$300+"
            },
```

Remove `,` after `Mississippi` block as no any block follow

```
            "Mississippi" => { bestYear => 2019,
                               Motto => "No motto", #Though someone will say, it's the 'In God We Trust' Plate
                               Color=> Blue on Gold
                               SignificanceofPlate=> "This is a very controversial plate because it feature the words, 'In God We Trust' on the plate" #It's mind boggling to me why it's controversial because Mississippi is a highly religious state. Possibly the most religious state.
                                priceOfplate=> "8.99" #This is very tricky because these plates are new so not many people are selling them. But I imagine they'll be expensive throughout the years. I have mine already :)
                             },        <-- remove , as no blocks follow
);
```

Last block edited by Polar Bear

```
print 
"<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Team</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1>License Plates</H1>
         <table border=1>
              <tr>
                  <th>Team</th>
                  <th>Year</th>
                  <th>Motto</th>
                  <th>Color</th> 
                  <th>Significance</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
             </tr>
";

for $teamName (sort keys %myTeams ) {
    $bestYear = $myTeams{$teamName}{'bestYear'};
    $Motto = $myTeams{$teamName}{'Motto'};
    $Color = $myTeams{$teamName}{'Color'};
    $SignificanceofPlate = $myTeams{$teamName}{'SignificanceofPlate'};
    $priceOfplate = $myTeams{$teamName}{'priceOfplate'};

    print 
"            <tr>
                   <td>$teamName</td>
                   <td>$bestYear</td>
                   <td>$Motto</td>
                   <td>$Color</td>
                   <td>$SignificanceofPlate</td>
                   <td>$priceOfplate</td>
             </tr>
";
}

print "
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
";
```

Comment: Mississippi block has `,` which should not be there. Last loop does not have any output - instead you print table header multiple times, Block of code for html does not require so many `print` statements -- 3 lines would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Polar Bear. I don't know if comments count towards popularity because you also have been very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Kelle -- just a suggestion if you work with html it would be beneficial to utilize power of [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/). It would allow you keep data and it's representation in two different baskets (easier to maintain -- a change of few lines in css file changes how whole website looks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a missing comma on the preceding line (26). The same error is repeated many times in the following lines.

You should also

```
use warnings;
```

to get additional information about potential problems in your code.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much!

Comment: And also `use strict`.